# asynchronously PAge loading for Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using an Selenium hybrid framework. Since pages on my Test application are asynchronous so I use explicit wait like visibilityOfElementLocated, elementtobeclickable, presenceofelement (rarely use this).

Now since page loads asynchronously so even after meeting these conditions, script fails. Scenario below:
I have Add button to click on. Now trigger for it has not loaded in browser (means code that defines its action has not loaded). but my selenium explicit condition is met.
So selenium clicks on button and nothing happens and script fails

How should this situation be handled.

Comment: probably you need to wait until complete page load rather than visibility of element..

Comment: It may not be a perfect solution. I see two limitations on it: 1) Implicit & explicit waits are not suggested to be used collectively.  2)  Application uses ajax a lot these days so implicit wont help much.